# Multi-Spectral High Resolution Satellite images for flood events

Tags: data, satellite, multi-band, flood, image-segmentation

I'm searching for multi-spectral high resolution satellite images for **flood events**. 
I found a database of flood events [from this link](http://floodobservatory.colorado.edu/) with dates and approxiamte locations (polygons) and I used the **Sentinel API hub** to download images. The problem is that images are too large and cannot found the intresting regions and cannot get images of the exact same location for two different dates. (to compare pre and post events).
Is there a way to get a **free dataset of high resolution satellite images for **flood events** (pre and post disater)? 
*BTW, I want to apply machine learning algorithms on  these images.*

Comment: For sources of open data I think it is worth visiting the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you reviewed this guide http://www.un-spider.org/advisory-support/recommended-practices/recommended-practice-flood-mapping/step-by-step?

Comment: @Marco I have seen that, but this is a "manual" tool to get images and if I want to get many of them it would be very time consuming to process it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using [Google Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com/): filter desired imagery by date (pre-post flood) and location (polygons of approximate locations). Machine learning algorithms like random forest is readily available there also.